# How can I detect when the magnifying glass is up in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I would like to augment the magnifying glass a bit, but I need a way of knowing when it comes up.

Comment: [Duplicate?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408776/how-can-i-know-when-the-magnifying-glass-comes-up-in-uiwebview